# Get values and keys from JSON in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have JSON in SQL Server:

```
[
    {
        "keyname": "keyname1",
        "valuename": "somestring"
    },
    {
        "keyname": "keyname2",
        "valuename": "somestring"
    },
    {
        "keyname": "keyname3",
        "valuename": 100
    }
]
```

Is it possible to search JSON by valuename e.g. "somestring" and return keyname and valuename.

I tried to use `JSON_VALUE` and `JSON_QUERY`:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(Mydata,'$[0].mydata') AS Mydata
FROM MyDataRows
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with a `WITH` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(N'[
    {
        "keyname": "keyname1",
        "valuename": "somestring"
    },
    {
        "keyname": "keyname2",
        "valuename": "somestring"
    },
    {
        "keyname": "keyname3",
        "valuename": 100
    }
]')
WITH (
    keyname   NVARCHAR(100) '$.keyname',
    valuename NVARCHAR(100) '$.valuename'
)
WHERE valuename = 'somestring'
```